# Outlook Missing Attachment Reminder for Mac

Tags: mac, microsoft-outlook, attachments

Obviously this is available in Outlook 2013 for Windows: https://www.howtogeek.com/tips/how-to-enable-or-disable-the-forgotten-attachment-reminder-in-outlook-2013/

But I cannot find equivalent settings in Outlook for Mac (v 15.39 (171010)). Can someone verify this is the case or am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Outlook for Mac 2016, there is no "Warn me when I send a message that may be missing an attachment" setting available like Windows.

The following article is the submitted feedback of this feature:
[forgotten attachment reminder Outlook for Mac](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/293343-outlook-for-mac/suggestions/15232467-forgotten-attachment-reminder)